# When using shiro to realize stateless application, do i need to login every request?

Tags: shiro, stateless

I use shiro and jwt and try to realize a stateless web application.
When i extend `AuthorizingRealm`, do i need to `executeLogin` every request?

Here is my `executeLogin` method:

```
 public static boolean executeLogin(ServletRequest request) {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authorization == null || "".equals(authorization.trim())) {
        throw RequestException.fail("未含授权标示，禁止访问");
    }
    JwtToken token = new JwtToken(authorization, null, null);
    // 提交给realm进行登入，如果错误他会抛出异常并被捕获
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    try {
        subject.login(token);
    } catch (DisabledAccountException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("verifyFail")) {
            throw new RequestException(ResponseCode.NOT_SING_IN.code, "身份已过期，请重新登录", e);
        }
        throw new RequestException(ResponseCode.SIGN_IN_INPUT_FAIL.code, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RequestException(ResponseCode.SIGN_IN_FAIL, e);
    }
    // 如果没有抛出异常则代表登入成功，返回true
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By Stateless means that each request does not depend from the previous, however this does not mean that Shiro does not use sessions.

When the user does a successful login Shiro attaches to the HTTPResponse some cookies. When the client sends the cookies to each further request, Shiro automatically extracts the Subject (associates the cookies with the user) so, in your code, you can immediately call `SecurityUtils.getSubject()`.

Answer (score 0):

A realm is the wrong approch here as it usually have by definition a 1-to-1 correlation with a data source. What you actually want to do is to controll access to your servers resources, verifying a JWT from a client.   This can be done by a [`AccessControlFilter`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/AccessControlFilter.html), reading the authorization header and verifing its claims in the filters `isAccessAllowed` method. The methods return value defines wheather access is allowed or not.

You don't need to login a subject at all since the `AccessControlFilter` decides wheather access is granted or denied, either forwarding the user to the requested resource or redirecting a 401 - Unauthorized response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should log in for each request.  This will attach the subject to the current thread and allow you to use features: like use annotations for authz.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using stateless call, you have to login each time and generate new subject and also load authorization details with appropriate realm.

The another option you could try is, put subject in cache (ehCache) once successful login and then on every request you can get subject from Cache and use for authorization. This will avoid login and authorization object population on every request. But you have to make sure to remove object from cache on logout event.

Similar thing has been already done by one user at:

https://github.com/jikechenhao/springmvc-shiro-react-redux-restful-example